# How can I copy a file from a usb drive to a directory on the hard drive in Centos 6?

Tags: centos

I would like to copy some files from a usb to a ssd hard drive running CentOS 6.5
How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Well for starters you'll need to determine the device handle assigned to the USB device when you plug it in. I typically use the command line tool `dmesg` to identify the USB device, after plugging it in.

#### Example

```
[657508.574443] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     PNY      USB 2.0 FD       8.02 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[657508.575169] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[657508.576653] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 15695871 512-byte logical blocks: (8.03 GB/7.48 GiB)
[657508.577428] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[657508.577435] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 08
[657508.578139] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[657508.578145] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[657508.581258] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[657508.581264] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[657508.585395]  sdb: sdb1
[657508.588151] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[657508.588158] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[657508.588163] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[657509.472676] SELinux: initialized (dev sdb1, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
```

The USB device is `/dev/sdb1` in my scenario, and can be mounted like this, manually:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Once mounted you can copy files to and from the mount point `/mnt` using the standard tools (`cp`, `mv`, etc.).

When done working on the USB device you'll want to unmount it like so:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

Followed by a `sync`:

```
$ sync
```

And then remove the USB drive.

#### References

- [Safely remove an USB hard drive in Linux](http://elliotli.blogspot.com/2009/01/safely-remove-usb-hard-drive-in-linux.html)

Comment: I would also recommend running sync before disconnecting the drive